# Working with CSS in React

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-redux, responsive

I am a beginner in React. I have been coding in AngularJS and bootstrap so far. I want to create an responsive application.

I have couple of questions to the developers who are already working on React:

1. My inclination towards something like bootstrap is because I do not want to spend a lot of time writing CSS. Bootstrap will give me ready CSS for common components like buttons, forms etc...but as bootstrap.js requires jQuery, does bootstrap works well with React? Can I use bootstrap 3 with React to create a responsive app? If not, is there any other CSS library I can use which works well for React?
2. In Angular, it was pretty easy to use some ready components from libraries like AngularUI which provided most common components one would ever need for an application. Is there any similar reliable library available alongside React as well which gives you common React components ?

I do not have any code samples at the moment because I have not really started yet and just want to get few doubts clarified first.

Comment: Guys , just noticed that this was put on hold...appreciate if could you please let me know what inputs are required from my side to better clarify my question?

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap css styles, you should use 
https://react-bootstrap.github.io
This is pretty good for react apps and it has many components with options to customize it's style.

Sorry, I'm not aware of any library like angular UI..

Comment: But they are not stable yet ..on their home page it says : "We are actively working to reach a 1.0.0 release"..

Comment: Well I've used it and I haven't faced any issues.. This is the most popular one that everyone uses in the react world as far as I know.. You can try it out.
Unfortunately, I don't know of any other alternative.